# lazy loading module does not load module js file

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, systemjs

I have two Modules that i am loading those modules with lazy loading.

1. AppModule
2. PassangerModule

AppModule is defined as follow

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        CabModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: CabComponent },
            { path: 'Cabs', component: CabComponent },
            { path: 'Passanger', loadChildren: 'App/Passanger/passanger.module#PassangerModule' }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CabComponent,
        CabFilterPipe,
        CabAddComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        CabService
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and ProductModule is defined as follow:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '', component: PassangerComponent
            }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        PassangerComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        PassangerService
    ]
})
export class PassangerModule {
}
```

Now when I navigated to /Products it does not work and tries GET request on `http://localhost:3000/App/Passanger/passanger.module` which is not valid path instead it should apply GET on `passanger.module.js`

I doubled checked that it is having defaultExtension as js in systemjs.config.js

Answer (score 1):

I changed the route module path and make `App/...` to lower case `app/...` and it worked.

I don't know why that string is case sensitive but it worked for me.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: CabComponent },
            { path: 'Cabs', component: CabComponent },
            { path: 'Passanger', loadChildren: 'app/Passanger/passanger.module#PassangerModule' }
        ])
```

Comment: Interesting! So it looks like the path is case sensitive then

Comment: @FredrikLundin folder name is `App` not `app`. Don't know why but it only works with lowercase name.

Comment: Reason for this tsconfig.json has option 
--forceConsistentCasingInFileNames by defaulse false. you can check this on below link
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html